# Non-homogeneous Markov chain on a finite state space

Tags: markov-chains

Let $\Omega$ be a finite state space. We consider a *non-homogeneous* Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ on $\Omega$. We denote for all $n\geq 1 $ and all $x,y\in\Omega$, $Q_n(x,y)=P(X_{n+1}=y|X_n=x)$.

Let $N\geq1$. Suppose that for all $n,n'\geq 1 $ and all $x,y\in\Omega$, if $n=n' \text{ mod } N$ then $$Q_n(x,y)=Q_{n'}(x,y)$$.

Let $H_x^t=\inf\{n\geq t+1|X_n =x\}$. We say that $x\in\Omega$ is recurrent if $P(H_x^t<\infty|X_t=x)=1$ for all $t\geq 1$.

Do standard result on recurrent and transient states for *homogeneous* Markov chains still hold in this context?

In particular, do we have that $R\subset \Omega$ is a recurrent class if and only if

1. $R$ is closed: for all $t\geq 1$, $P(X_{t+1}\notin R | X_t\in R) = 0$
2. $R$ is communicating: for all $x,y\in R$ and all $t\geq 1$, there exists $t',t''\geq 0$ such that $P(X_{t+t'}=y|X_t=x)>0$ and  $P(X_{t+t''}=x|X_t=y)>0$.

Comment: And where exactly do the standard proofs fail?